# Oracle FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble with Oracle SQL.

When executing the following query
`SELECT * FROM "myschema"."mytable" ORDER BY "mycolumn" fetch first 1 rows only FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;`
the driver complains that:

> "`FOR UPDATE` and `ORDER BY` cannot be executed in the same query

I understand this, but can someone point me to the correct way of combining this statement, maybe into subqueries?

Already had a look at some similar issues, but could not really figure out how the solutions map to my specific problem.

Comment: It's the `fetch` clause that's causing the error, not the `order by` per se. (It's helpful to show the actual full error code and message you get - presumably ORA-02014 here.) Are you doing this in SQL as it appears (in which case what are you trying to achieve?), or in PL/SQL - is it actually part of a cursor query?

Answer (score 0):

You can first order the rows in a subquery and then apply FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in the outer query.
Here's an example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM "myschema"."mytable"
ORDER BY "mycolumn"
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
) subquery
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

In this query, the inner subquery orders the rows by mycolumn and fetches the first row. The outer query then applies FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED to the result of the subquery.

Keep in mind that FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED is available from Oracle Database 10g Release 1 onwards. Also, the FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY syntax is available from Oracle Database 12c Release 1 onwards. If you're using an older version of Oracle Database, you can use the ROWNUM pseudo-column instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROWNUM AS rn
    FROM "myschema"."mytable"
    ORDER BY "mycolumn"
) subquery
WHERE subquery.rn = 1
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

Comment: If the original need is to get the first unlocked row none of the solutions will give the expected result: you will get the first row ordered by "my column" if unlocked but nothing if this one is locked, even if unlocked rows exist.

Comment: They also [both still error](https://dbfiddle.uk/sIRKbDLw).

Comment: Right, I already went down the subquery path - this still gives ORA-02014

Answer (score 0):

It's the `fetch first ...` clause that is causing the error, rather than the `order by`; you're allowed to order the results, but it seems trying to restrict them [doesn't work](https://dbfiddle.uk/sIRKbDLw).

I'm not sure it's possible to just get (and lock) one row in SQL.

You can do it in PL/SQL by using a cursor and only fetching once:

```
declare
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  l_row "myschema"."mytable"%rowtype;
begin
  open l_cursor for
    SELECT * FROM "myschema"."mytable" ORDER BY "mycolumn" FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
  fetch l_cursor into l_row;
  if l_cursor%found then
    dbms_output.put_line(l_row."mycolumn");
  end if;
  close l_cursor;
end;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dz3Ilhf1)

But that might not achieve whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. So, I am trying to adapt a third library package in .NET that has integrations for Postgres and MySql, but not for Oracle. The only db-specific part is a formatter for a specific query that this package has to make, which, in postgres, looks like this:
`SELECT * FROM "myschema"."mytable" ORDER BY "mycolumn" LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`.
I thought it might be as easy as adopting this query to Oracle SQL, but if that does not work in a single statement, I will have to go a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I am now trying to decouple the query using a function and cursors

```
create or replace function GetColumnValue
   return number is myId number;
   l_cursor sys_refcursor;
   l_row "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE"%rowtype;
begin
   open l_cursor for
      SELECT "Id" FROM "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" ORDER BY "Id" FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
      fetch l_cursor into l_row;
      if l_cursor%found then
          myId := l_row."Id";
      end if;
   close l_cursor;
   return myId;
end;
```

And then calling it like

```
select * from "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" where "Id" = GETCOLUMNVALUE();
```

But that gives me ORA-14551 (cannot perform a DML operation inside a query).
So maybe that's not possible as well. I really am an Oracle beginner, so any insight is appreciated.